# Orchard CMS Image Gallery

Tags: orchardcms, azure-web-app-service

I have created an orchard site using the Azure Websites Gallery option.

I would like to add a simple Gallery module so that I can display multiple images on a page. 
Does anyone know of a tutorial explaining how to do this? It seems that popular gallery modules such as http://orchardimagegallery.codeplex.com/ don't work with v1.7 of Orchard (which is what I got with Azure) because of missing dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the MediaLibraryPicker field 
or this module : https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/nwazet.zengallery

Comment: Thanks Antoine, the nwazet gallery module seems to be perfect - If I can just figure out how to use it!